# functions return functions that return functions javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

How do I get this to return a value for x+y+z instead of an error?

```
function A (x) {
    return function B (y) {
        return function(z) {
            return x+y+z;
        }
    }
};

var outer = new A(4);
var inner = new outer(B(9));
inner(4);
```

Comment: The code works fine. What do you want to achieve? Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: No "new"s needed here, you can call it like `A(2)(3)(4)` or `var f = A(2); var g = f(3); alert(g(4));`, pretty much the same ...

Comment: yent..Thanks for the great answer. Please make that an answer. Jeff...No it doesnt work, did you try it? "B in undefined". rid....its returning x+y+z. just a proof of concept.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  For all we know, you want the program to illustrate runtime errors with regards to undefined functions.  In that case, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like yent said, no "new"s are necessary. "new" returns an instance.

For instance (pun intended):

```
function foo(a){
    return a;
}

foo(4);    // this will return 4, but
new foo(); // this will return a 'foo' object
```

But now on to your question. Like rid said, B is declared within the scope of function A. So, your `new outer(B(9));` will throw an error because B doesn't exist in the scope of where you called it.

Secondly, back to what yent said. Since each function is returning a function, we call what was returned.

```
function A (x) {
    return function B (y) {
        return function C (z) {
            return x+y+z;
        }
    }
};

var f = A(2); // f is now function B, with x = 2
var g = f(3); // g is now function C, with x = 2, and y = 3
var h = g(4); // Function C returns x+y+z, so h = 2 + 3 + 4 = 9
```

However, we can use the following 'shortcut':

```
A(2)(3)(4);
// each recursive '(x)' is attempting to call the value in front of it as if it was a function (and in this case they are).
```

To sort of explain:

```
A(2)(3)(4) = ( A(2)(3) )(4) = ( ( A(2) )(3) )(4);

// A(2) returns a function that we assigned to f, so
( ( A(2) )(3) )(4) = ( ( f )(3) )(4) = ( f(3) )(4);

// We also know that f(3) returns a function that we assigned to g, so
( f(3) )(4) = g(4);
```

I hope that helped!